# Convert a textbox to autocomplete in c# wpf window?

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, textbox

I am building a desktop application using WPF in VisualStudio 2013.

I have a WPF window with a textbox.

How can I convert this textbox to autocomplete?

Comment: Here is an interesting article that I hope you will find helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox

Comment: It's hard to answer your question if you don't provide any code. However, the article Roger mentioned should help you.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use a ComboBox rather than a TextBox. The ComboBox supports autocomplete. In WPF you can then use a TextBox template to override the standard ComboBox template. My advice is to use the ComboBox as it is.

```
    <ComboBox Name="CBox" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEditable="True" >
        <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Four</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Two2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Two2b</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

You can also use the AutoComplete TextBox from CodePlex:  http://wpfactb.codeplex.com/